# How to solve two jquery confliction specially autocomplete and fullcalendar js

Tags: jquery, html

I want to include two jquery files (one is for auto complete ajax and other is for full calendar) on the same page/ header page but it will conflict each other. How I can solved this issue, I already tried the solution of noConflict but no use, please help me.
Following is my code to include js file:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/fullcalendar/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

where first file is used for auto complete dropdown and other one is for full calendar event.

Comment: Why can't you use just one jQuery file for both?

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried it but if I comment any one js then one of the functionality not work whose js I commented I mean if I use only jQuery-1.2.1.min.js then my fullcalendar having problem and if I use only other then ajax auto complete not work, any other solution please ?

Comment: Use a higher version Jquery maybe? Where both your functionalities would work.

Comment: @Dorvalla, let me try.

Comment: @Dorvalla, I downloaded jQuery version 1.7 but no use, please help me for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Sorry, I just saw you tried noConflict after posting this.  The only reason I could think it would not work is if you are not wanting to update the $/Jquery names in one of the files.  You could do this with a find and replace pretty easily.

I would recommend using jQuery.noConflict(true) to remove the JQuery object from the global scope and assign it to an object name of your choosing, provided you don't need to use the precise object name: JQuery/$ to access the JQuery object for both versions.  You can do this for one of the versions after inclusion.

For example: jq121 = jQuery.noConflict( true ); would let you access version 1.2.1 as jq121 in global scope.  If called after the inclusion of 1.2.1, this would free up $ and JQuery to reference your other version.

They have some examples here:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Edit: I put together a quick example.  With the below code you can access the newer version with jq214 and the older version with the default $ alias.

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
        
          jq214 = jQuery.noConflict( true );
          jq214(document.body).append("jq214 object name is version " + jq214.fn.jquery);
          $(document.body).append("<br/>default $ alias is version " + $.fn.jquery);
        
        });
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I should mention though that the JQuery team mentions (as others here do) that including two versions should be avoided if possible.

Comment: thank you for your reply and valuable suggestion with example.